# Is this true? [(∀x)A(x) → (∀x)B(x)] → [(∀x)(A(x) → B(x))]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is this proposition True?  [(∀x)A(x) → (∀x)B(x)] → [(∀x)(A(x) → B(x))

I cannot think if there is a difference between the first implication and the last one. Therefore, I think the proposition is true, although I  got someone saying that the proposition is false, again, for the proposition to be false, there must be a difference between (∀x)A(x) → (∀x)B(x) and(∀x)(A(x) → B(x).

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, but I think the reason you're getting downvotes is because you haven't shown your attempts at solving this problem on your own. Questions that consist of just the statement and nothing else is frowned upon.

Comment: Oh Sorry. I didn't know that.  Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The proposition is false. For example, consider the case that the universe of $x$ is $\mathbb{R}$. $A(x):= x>1$ and $B(x):= x>3$.  In this case $(\forall x)A(x)$ is false. Hence $(\forall x)A(x)\rightarrow (\forall x)B(x)$ is true, regardless of $(\forall x)B(x)$. However, $(\forall x)(A(x)\rightarrow B(x))$ is false .

Comment: Why would (∀x)(A(x)→B(x))  be false if you said that  (∀x)(A(x) is false too?

Comment: (∀x)(A(x)→B(x)) is translated to "For any real number, if x>1, then x>3", which is obviously false.(For example, x=2 is a counter-example). (∀x)(A(x)) is translated to "For any real number x, x>1" which is also false.

Comment: (∀x)A(x)→(∀x)B(x) is therefore true because (∀x)A(x) is false. (Recall that if $P$ is false, then $P\rightarrow Q$ is always true, regardless of $Q$).

Comment: Finally, (∀x)A(x)→(∀x)B(x)  is true, while (∀x)(A(x)→B(x)) is false, so [(∀x)A(x)→(∀x)B(x) ])→[(∀x)(A(x)→B(x))] is false. (Recall that (true→false) is false)